# Laravel getting users from multiple messages

Tags: laravel

I've got `offers` table with `id`'s

`Messages` table with columns `offer_id` and `from`

and `Users` table with `id`'s

I want to get users starting with offer `$this` in `OfferResource`
My goal is to get users that have replied to the offer with at least one message.

I started to configure `Offer` model with function messages to get messages

```
public function messages(){
    return $this -> hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

so I'm able to get all messages (starting from offer resource):

`'users' => $this->messages`

How should I now configure messages model to get all users instead of messages?

I tried to write in `Message` model :

```
public function fromContact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'from');
}
```

and then:

`'users' => $this->messages->fromContact`

but i've got error: `"message": "Property [fromContact] does not exist on this collection instance.",`

How should I correct my code to make this work?

Comment: because `$this->messages` will return a collection you have to loop over it to get one message and then use `$message->fromContact` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the `from` field on the `Messages` table is populated using user ID. Then you could establish `belongsToMany` relationship between the `Offer` and `User` models. Since this is actually a many-to-many relation with a pivot table `messages`.

In the `Offer` model define

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'messages', 'offer_id', 'from');
}
```

Then from the `OfferResource` you could load the `offers` data like this—

`$offers = App\Offer::with('users')->get();`

Then loop over the `$offers` like this:

```
foreach ($offers as $offer) {
    dd($offer->users); // one offer will have multiple users as a Collection
}
```

Similarly for an `$offer` of ID `1` you could do this

`$offer = App\Offer::with('users')->find(1)`

Then to get the `users` that commented on this offer just use `$offer->users`

See the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for defining many-to-many relationship.

Comment: I'm reading docs, but this is not so simple in practice, let me try this out

Comment: error in OfferResource: `"message": "Class 'App\\Http\\Resources\\App\\Offer' not found",`

Comment: Could you please try `$offers = \App\Offer::with('users')->get();` this instead of `$offers = App\Offer::with('users')->get();`?

The thing is, use proper namespaced `Offer` model. I omitted a slash ( `\\` ) in the answer.

Comment: again: `"message": "Class 'App\\Http\\Resources\\App\\Offer' not found",`
It seems like you cannot make any queries inside Resource class

Comment: Where is your `Offer` model located? Could you please let me know the namespaced class name?

Comment: Okay, please wait I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: standard location: `App\Offer;`

Comment: Sorry, not working, I've got to small experience to figure it out. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Could you please let me know the code that you have before instantiating the OfferResource? It would be best if I have all the code block for this section.

Comment: I'll try to do it more simple way - to get all messages and then get users to each of them and then call unique() on them to delete duplications, I cannot learn new things for now :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174183/discussion-between-adre-astrian-and-gileneusz).

Answer (score 1):

In the Message model you have to spesify the column that refer to the user :

```
public function fromContact()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'from');
}
```

And then after geting the messages loop over them to get the user like this :

```
foreach ($this->messages as $message) {
    $user = $message->fromContact;
    // do somthing with the user :)
}
```

Comment: thank you for this advice, I'll try this out, however isn't it possible to do it within the single query? To use some kind of Laravel built-in methods?

Comment: I don't know a way other than user a query on the users table and join it with messages and offers table !

Answer (score 1):

Your messages table has `from` field that is referencing `User` model and `offer_id` field which referencing `Offer` model that means you have ManyToMany relations between `Offer` and `User`.

**Offer Model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'messages', 'offer_id', 'from')->using('App\Message');
}
```

**Message Pivot**

```
class Message extends Pivot {
     protected $table = 'messages';
}
```

**User model**

```
public function offers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Offer::class, 'messages', 'from', 'offer_id')->using('App\Message');
}
```

**OfferResource**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $users = $this->users; 

    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        ... //add your offer fields here
        'users' => $users->toArray(), // here $users is a laravel Collection
        'created_at' => $this->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
    ];
}
```

**Access from Controller or Route**

```
Route::get('/offer', function () {
    return new OfferResource(Offer::with('users')->find(1)); //eager load users
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this but it gives an error in Message Model: `"message": "syntax error, unexpected '$table' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)",`

Comment: please add `protected $table = 'messages'`

Comment: @gileneusz did you try this ?

Comment: I'm trying just now

Comment: after adding simply:  `$users = Offer::with('users')->find($this->id);
        return $users;` to my OfferResource I've got CRSF errors, which means that everything is wrong :) sorry, I need a break, this is very very simple question and laravel cannot handle it :/

Comment: @gileneusz i have updated answer with `OfferResource` `toArray()`. try changing with this. should work now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174182/discussion-between-gileneusz-and-rkj).

Comment: @gileneusz i have updated answer with adding your `OfferResource` and accessing it through controller. if you interested then you can try

Comment: I don't know how to set pivot on my existing `Message` class, this throws errors